# Getting started with Ads on Android

Tags: android, ads

Any advice on how to get started setting up ads in an Android application? I don't know what I need to know about ads in general.

I save admob being most frequently mentioned. Are there any other options?

Comment: There is a list of advertising networks/services [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6262918/741249)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I myself use Admob. Create an account, and create a key for your app [here](http://www.admob.com/my_sites/). Then download the library, add it to your project, and in your layout file, add something like this:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="@YOURKEY"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
```

Also, add this line at the top of the layout file:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

Finally, you'll need to add this to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

That is really all there is up to creating ads in your app. For more information, see [this](http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android#AdMob_Android_SDK).

Answer (score 1):

You will propably hear about Mobclix, my personal experience with them has been horrible. There's also a couple of forum threads out there that have a lot of bad stuff to say about them. Admob is a stable network. You get paid on time. If you're looking for full screen ads, you may look into Greystripe. I just started using greystripe myself so I'm not 100% about them.

Answer (score 1):

I advise **against** using AdMob directly.
Instead use a mediation service called [AdWhirl](http://code.google.com/p/adwhirl/) (owned by AdMob/Google).

This way you can use ads from multiple sources (Admob, Adsense, ZestAdz, Millenialmedia...) in your app and decide how many ads you want to pull from each service later.
Btw. AdWhirl doesn't charge for this service.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use a combination of MobFox, Admob, and MobClix.  While MobClix has indicated they're cleaning up their payment system, I can't recommend them for newbies  yet.

I wrote a guide for getting MobFox and Admob into your app (actually just using one of the SDKs to keep it easier) and using MobFox to only serve the high-paying ads.  Hopefully it can help you get started:
http://www.projectjourneyman.com/android-income-quickstart-guide

Answer (score 0):

I got banned by admob for some unknown reason and switched to millenialmedia - it worked out pretty  well though, Millenial Media seem to pay much more than admob, and they always rely to my emails.

I don't work for them at all.